# How to read manifest file from dependent JAR in Android?

Tags: android, jar, manifest

Does anyone know how to read values from MANIFEST.MF from my custom dependent JAR in Android ?
I`ve tried many ways but it seems that they do not work for Android environment.

Comment: You want to read the MANIFEST.MF of one of your libraries?

Comment: That`s correct. I`ve dig in this question, and it seems that this is impossible. =(

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(stream);
Manifest mf = jarStream.getManifest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the custom dependent jar also as a resource in your apk file, then you can read it somehow.
As a custom dependency only, you are not allowed to read the jar file, or you will get false results.